# How to query value in numeric order?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-filter

Suppose I have a model

```
class Industry(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length = 100)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    order_as = models.IntegerField()
```

How can i query data in view basing on numeric values i have given in `order_as` column to some `Industry` and others in alphabetical order.

```
if name is None:
    filters = models.Q()
    industry_results = Industry.objects.filter(filters,status='1').order_by('-order_as','-id').values('order_as','id').exclude(name__isnull=True).distinct('order_as')
```

Comment: Please give us some examples of the data and the ordering you want to clarify the question.

Comment: your question is not very clear. Please clarify with some example